# get all dependencies with versions in spring-context 4.3.6.Release

Tags: spring

How to get the list of all dependencies with versiosn used in spring-context 4.3.6 Release ? I do see that for spring boot in spring.io page but not for spring-context

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven adding this will resolve all dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

It has following dependencies:

> org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.6.RELEASE
>   org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.6.RELEASE
>   org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.6.RELEASE
>   org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.6.RELEASE
>   commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
>   org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.6.RELEASE

Comment: Need is to know all open source used in the product. Not asking for maven dependency here.

Comment: by visiting https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context/4.3.6.RELEASE you will see a compile dependencies section, is that what you're looking for?